# How to map two dataframes based on splitted items in the columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe as follows:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['Drama', 'Tennis Elbow', 'Cricket & bat', 'Ant and Boat'],
    'Items': ['abc, def, kgf, do work', 'ball, jig, file code, sensor dye, gun', 'jack and jill, common, bitter', 
             'ram, krish, myran']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df1

```
    Name            Items
0   Drama           abc, def, kgf, do work
1   Tennis Elbow    ball, jig, file code, sensor dye, gun
2   Cricket & bat   jack and jill, common, bitter
3   Ant and Boat    ram, krish, myran
```

and

```
data2 = {
    'values': ['abc and sea', 'def work', 'abc', 'ram cold', 'myran add', 'check'],
    'gems': ['A1, A2, A3, A4', 'B1, A1, B2, B3', 'C1, A1', 'KS, KM', 'JP, CVK', 'KF, GF']  
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df2

```
    values        gems
0   abc and sea   A1, A2, A3, A4
1   def work      B1, A1, B2, B3
2   abc           C1, A1
3   ram cold      KS, KM
4   myran add     JP, CVK
5   check         KF, GF
```

I want to map strings or string contains items from `df1['Items']` to the `df2['values']` and create a new dataframe with mapped values in a new column as follows:

```
    values        gems              Name
0   abc and sea   A1, A2, A3, A4    Drama
1   def work      B1, A1, B2, B3    Drama
2   abc           C1, A1            Drama
3   ram cold      KS, KM            Ant and Boat
4   myran add     JP, CVK           Ant and Boat
```

Comment: What should the output be if a value occurs in multiple items? For example, "abc and ball"? Or does that never happen?

Comment: @not_speshal that never happen

Comment: Why does `def work` match `do work`?

Comment: @HenryEcker  partial strings `def ` and `work` comes under `Drama`

Comment: @not_speshal splitting on comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the column `Items` on comma, strip off any remaining white  spaces, then explode and reset the index

```py
>>> df1['Items'] = df1['Items'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x:[i.strip() for i in x])
>>> df1 = df1.explode('Items').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then write a function, that will return `Name` or `NaN`, for a provided value `x` based on the condition whether `x` contains any of the value in `Items` column, if yes, return the first value, else return `NaN`.

```py
>>> def getName(x):
        return next(iter(df1.loc[df1['Items'].apply(lambda item: item in x)]['Name']),
                    np.nan)
```

Finally, apply the function `getName` on `values` column of the second dataframe, assign it to a new column `Name`, and drop the rows where `Name` is `NaN`.

```py
>>> df2.assign(Name=df2['values'].apply(getName)).dropna(subset=['Name'])

        values            gems          Name
0  abc and sea  A1, A2, A3, A4         Drama
1     def work  B1, A1, B2, B3         Drama
2          abc          C1, A1         Drama
3     ram cold          KS, KM  Ant and Boat
4    myran add         JP, CVK  Ant and Boat
```

Comment: in my real data there is a phrase mapped: 'abnormal heart morphology MP:0000266' which is not really required. It got mapped due to `hear` word in the mapping list. I want to map the term only when `heart` is mapped not `hear`

Comment: How can apply case_sensitive=False, here

Comment: For `case_insensitive`, one way you can do is you can convert both the values to lower string and do the comparison, i.e. `item.lower() in x.lower()` in `lambda` function of `getName`

Comment: And for better performance, you can convert all the values in `Items` column of `df1` to lower case upfront, i.e. `df1['Items']  = df1['Items'].str.lower()` after exploding and resetting the index, then `tem in x.lower()` inside the `lambda` of `getName` function.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a mapping dictionary from df1 and use that to map values from df2.

1. `split` the words df1["Items"] and `explode` the resulting column of lists to create the mapper for each word:

```
df1["Items"] = df1["Items"].str.split(", ")
mapper = df1.explode("Items")
mapper = dict(zip(mapper["Items"], mapper["Name"]))
```

2. Use the mapper to get the names for the words in df2["values"].

```
df2["Name"] = df2["values"].apply(lambda x: " ".join([mapper.get(word,"") for word in x.split()]).strip())
df2 = df2[df2["Name"]!=""]
```

##### Output:

```
>>>> df2
        values            gems          Name
0  abc and sea  A1, A2, A3, A4         Drama
1     def work  B1, A1, B2, B3         Drama
2          abc          C1, A1         Drama
3     ram cold          KS, KM  Ant and Boat
4    myran add         JP, CVK  Ant and Boat
```